# my loop are confuse in multiple list difference size in flask

Tags: python, list, for-loop, flask

I want a result like:

```
1:                    
2:    
3: 3 p3 33  
4: 4 p4 44  
....  
...
```

But what I get is

```
1:  
2:  
3: 3 p3 33  
3: 4 p4 44  
3: 7 p7 77  
...
```

This is my python code

```
str1 = [3,4,7,9]
n_save = ['p3','p4','p7','p9']
d_save = ['33','44','77','99']
zipped = zip(str1,n_save,d_save)
 
# flask code
 
    {% for i in range(0,10) %}<br>
    {% if i+1 in str1|list %}
        {% for numm,namee,dd in zipped %}

    <option value="{{ i+1 }}">  {{ i+1 }} : {{ namee }} {{ dd }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
        <option value="{{ i+1 }}"> {{ i+1 }} : </option>
   {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is at

```
    <option value="{{ i+1 }}">  {{ i+1 }} : {{ namee }} {{ dd }}</option>
  % endfor %}
```

You are looping through the entire zipped array which is currently [(3, 'p3', '33'), (4, 'p4', '44'), (7, 'p7', '77'), (9, 'p9', '99')]

What you want is to only get the members of the tuple at a particular position i.e.

if i+1 = 3 which is at position 0 of str1, then only get values of zipped[0]

if i+1 = 4 which is at position 1 of str1, then only get values of zipped[1]

Try

```
    <!-- first convert to a list -->
    {% set k = zipped|list %}

        {% for i in range(0,10) %}<br>
            {% if i+1 in str1|list %}
                <!-- find the position of i + 1 -->
                {% set j = str1.index(i+1) %}
                <!-- get the value at that position -->
                {% set l = k[j] %}
                
            <option value="{{ i+1 }}">  {{ i+1 }} : {{ l[0] }} {{ l[1] }} {{l[2]}}</option>
                    
           {% else %}
                <option value="{{ i+1 }}"> {{ i+1 }} : </option>
           {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
```

Tested this and got

1

2

3 : 3 p3 33

4 : 4 p4 44

5

6

7 : 7 p7 77

Comment: Thank you, but not work for me. All result are else.

Comment: Updated the code and tested it. It outputs what you said you want

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, the iterator is first converted into a list.
A pointer to the current index of the zipped list is then created using a [namespace](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-globals.namespace).
Now the respective entry of the list can be unpacked.

```
{% set data = zipped | list -%}
{% set ctx = namespace(index0=0) -%}
{% for i in range(1,11) -%}
  {% if ctx.index0 < (data | length) and i == data[ctx.index0][0] -%}
    {% set _, namee, dd = data[ctx.index0] -%}
    <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }} : {{ namee }} {{ dd }}</option>
    {% set ctx.index0 = ctx.index0 + 1 -%}
  {% else -%}
    <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }} : </option>
  {% endif -%}
{% endfor -%}
```